# How to test model binder in ASP.Net MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to write a unit test for a custom model binder in ASP.Net MVC 6. It seems simple enough. The model binder has a single `BindModelAsync` method which takes a `ModelBindingContext` parameter.

In my unit test, I'm trying to figure out how to fake the `ModelBindingContext`. At first, I thought I could use the default constructor and set the properties on the object that I need. This works for all of the properties except `ModelType` which is not settable.

I then looked at the static `ModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext` but it takes a bunch of scary looking parameters. Looking at [how some of the model binding tests](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c116a38c87ef7a32f40659d393cae25677dfbdbd/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Test/ModelBinding/HeaderModelBinderTests.cs#L119) within the MVC repo are written, it seems like it is not possible for me to mock the `ModelBindingContext.ModelType` (unless maybe I copy/paste those 6 classes from [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TestCommon](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TestCommon/TestModelMetadataProvider.cs)).

Is there something simple/easy I am missing?

Comment: Can't you write your `BindModelAsync` method not to depend on `ModelBinderContext` but rather on an interface that wraps around it? Then it's possible to unit test. Also your question sounds like more you need integration tests, rather than unit tests, as `ModelBindingContext` can't be mocked or tested easily without adding a bunch of other dependencies, and this makes it an integration test (require interaction between multiple components). For an integration test you don't seem to have much of a choice as that do it like the Asp:Net Core team

Answer (score 8):

I've had some success in getting it working for some simple form and query string values. AspNetCore.Mvc v1.1.3

```cs
private static DefaultModelBindingContext GetBindingContext(IValueProvider valueProvider, Type modelType)
{
    var metadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var bindingContext = new DefaultModelBindingContext
    {
        ModelMetadata = metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelType),
        ModelName = modelType.Name,
        ModelState = new ModelStateDictionary(),
        ValueProvider = valueProvider,
    };
    return bindingContext;
}
```

Using a query string provider

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task QueryStringValueProviderTest()
{
    var binder = new MyModelBinder();

    var queryCollection = new QueryCollection(
        new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
        {
            { "param1", new StringValues("1") },
            { "param2", new StringValues("2") },
        });
    var vp = new QueryStringValueProvider(BindingSource.Query, queryCollection, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    var context = GetBindingContext(vp, typeof(MyModel));

    await binder.BindModelAsync(context);

    var resultModel = context.Result.Model as MyModel;

    //TODO Asserts
}
```

Using a form collection provider

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task FormValueProviderTest()
{
    var binder = new MyModelBinder();

    var formCollection = new FormCollection(
        new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
        {
            { "param1", new StringValues("1") },
            { "param2", new StringValues("2") }
        });
    var vp = new FormValueProvider(BindingSource.Form, formCollection, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    var context = GetBindingContext(vp, typeof(MyModel));

    await binder.BindModelAsync(context);

    var resultModel = context.Result.Model as MyModel;

    //TODO asserts
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. The query string example was exactly what I needed. You'd think Microsoft would have some good documentation on unit testing model binding since it's so widely used...

Comment: For the record, this works with ASP.NET **Core** MVC as well